# Can I rename Liferea feeds imported from Google?

Tags: rss, liferea

I sync Liferea with Google Reader in order to only have to maintain my (lengthy) list of feeds in one place.  Many of the feeds have annoyingly long names which I have renamed in Google Reader to be much shorter.

However, it looks like Liferea is not using the new name from Google Reader, but rather the name of the feed itself.  Any way to fix this or rename them in Liferea?

Answer (score 0):

No this is actually not possible. Liferea will always restore the name from Google Reader.

Comment: Thanks for responding, but shouldn't Liferea use the new name I gave the feed in Google Reader instead of always using the original name?